# What affects DB2 restored database size?

Tags: db2, backup, restore

I have database TESTDB with following details:

Database size: 3.2GB

Database Capacity: 302 GB

One of its tablespaces has its HWM too high due to an SMP extent, so it is not letting me reduce the high water mark.

My backup size is around 3.2 GB (As backups contains only used pages)

If I restore this database backup image via a redirected restore, what will be the newly restored database's size?

Will it be around 3.2 GB or around 302 GB?

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is that `RESTORE DATABASE` will produce a target database that occupies about as much disk space as the source database did when it was backed up.

On its own, the size of a DB2 backup image is not a reliable indicator of how big the target database will be. For one thing, DB2 provides the option to compress the data being backed up, which can make the backup image significantly smaller than the DB2 object data it contains.

As you correctly point out, the backup image only contains non-empty extents (blocks of contiguous pages), but the `RESTORE DATABASE` command will recreate each tablespace container to its original size (including empty pages) unless you specify different container locations and sizes via the `REDIRECT` parameter.

The 302GB of capacity you're seeing is from `GET_DBSIZE_INFO` and similar utilities, and is quite often larger than the total storage the database currently occupies. This is because DB2's capacity calculation includes not only unused pages in DMS tablespaces, but also any free space on volumes or drives that are used by an SMS tablespace (most DB2 LUW databases contain at least one SMS tablespace).